# Question about go-around trajectory

Tags: go-around

What does ATC expect you to do if you go around on a visual approach, considering you were never cleared for an instrument approach? Do you set go-around altitude according to the instrument approach or to circuit altitude?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On a "Visual Approach", do I execute a "missed approach" or do I go around?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20866/on-a-visual-approach-do-i-execute-a-missed-approach-or-do-i-go-around)

Comment: Could you clarify if your question is regarding flying VFR into a controlled airfield?

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a visual approach flying VFR, you go around at circuit height and remain in the circuit.

If you're cleared for an instrument approach you would have been given missed approach procedure, or you follow the standard missed approach.

If in any doubt, ask. That's what they're there for.

---

As you called this a "circuit" and not a "pattern" I'm making an assumption you're flying in the UK. If I'm right, there's a couple of subtle hints there when you request joining info.

The standard phrasing goes something like:

> [Station] Approach, G-ABCD, 10 miles south west, request join.
> G-ABCD, [Station] Approach, QFE 1012, Runway 27 in use, **right hand circuit**, traffic is **a Cessna 152 in the circuit** and a PA-28 on a 4 mile final. Join overhead, Report entering the ATZ.

In bold are your two hints that the approach controller (in this example) is expecting you to enter the visual circuit. They have both told you the circuit direction, and given you some basic information about the traffic currently in or near the ATZ.

Comment: Your example seems to use a VFR pilot. I'm not sure if it's different outside of FAA-land, but within FAA-Land it is very clear that a "visual approach" is an IFR-specific procedure.

Comment: @randomhead A visual approach is an IFR-specific procedure in EASA-land as well :) Albeit one without a defined missed approach procedure, hence the original question

Comment: Yeah I've made a bold assumption here which might well be wrong.